# Facebook PHP SDK - how to get a long lived page access token

Tags: php, facebook

Having this code, which works:

```
        $appsecretProof = hash_hmac('sha256', $shortLivedToken, $secret);

        //init curl
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'facebook-php-3.2');

        //get extended user access token
        $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token' .
            '&client_id=' . $appId .
            '&client_secret=' . $secret .
            '&fb_exchange_token=' . $shortLivedToken .
            '&appsecret_proof=' . $appsecretProof;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        $curlResult = curl_exec($ch);
        $response_params = [];
        parse_str($curlResult, $response_params);
        $extendedUserToken = $response_params['access_token'];

        $appsecretProof = hash_hmac('sha256', $extendedUserToken, $secret);
        //get extended page access token
        $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $pageId .
            '?fields=access_token' .
            '&access_token=' . $extendedUserToken .
            '&appsecret_proof=' . $appsecretProof;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        $curlResult = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $pageToken = json_decode($curlResult)->access_token;
```

How to achieve the same using the regular Facebook SDK? Googling didn't really help. Either I find nothing usable or the solutions do not work, throwing errors like "An access token is required to request this resource" or similar stuff. I already tried a lot but nothing really works.

My last approach was:

```
        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($appId, $secret);

        $shortLivedSession = new FacebookSession($shortLivedToken);
        $shortLivedSession->getLongLivedSession();

        $request = new FacebookRequest($shortLivedSession, 'GET', '/' . $pageId . '?fields=access_token');
        $response = $request->execute();
        $result = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
        $pageToken = $result['access_token'];
        $facebookSession = new FacebookSession($pageToken);
```

This code always returns a short-lived token.

Comment: hey, that looks like the code from my blogpost :) > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25844782/facebook-php-sdk-how-to-get-a-long-lived-page-access-token

Comment: Yes and you can't imagine how GRATEFUL I am for this.

Comment: Can you help me with this?

Comment: anyway, try debugging the short lived token i the facebook debugger. maybe there is something wrong with that one.

Comment: No, the token was OK. It must be something with the code.

Comment: ok, then i have no clue, unfortunately. the code looks good, but i try to avoid the php sdk as much as possible. too much overhead, i mostly use the js sdk anyway...

Comment: Yes, but with JS you would never get a long-lived token.

Comment: but you get the short-lived one and you can transfer it to the server - and then use simple curl calls to generate and store it.

Comment: Using Curl is exactly what we don't want to do. That's why Facebook created its SDK-s...

Comment: well, the SDK uses curl too. it always depends on the project, but if you only need to use PHP for some small api calls, it would be a bit too much to use the whole sdk - with 4.0 it became pretty large :)

Comment: You are right with this. But in this particular case the project is huge and we use more facebook functions than just this. So, using SDK is appreciated by the team leader :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out and @luschn, there seems to be the same error in the code on your blog.

What helped was to replace these two lines:

```
    $shortLivedSession->getLongLivedSession();

    $request = new FacebookRequest($shortLivedSession, 'GET', '/' . $pageId . '?fields=access_token');
```

with these:

```
    $longLivedSession = $shortLivedSession->getLongLivedSession();

    $request = new FacebookRequest($longLivedSession, 'GET', '/' . $pageId . '?fields=access_token');
```

Comment: what do you mean? i recently used the curl code in a project, there was no error.

Comment: Sorry, I was too fast. I mean this article http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/. I am not sure if you are the author. But we actually have to assign the return value of `getLongLivedSession()` to something.

Comment: great :) now everyone can enjoy it. Btw your blog posts help people a lot and save them tons of time. Thanks for them.